# Why can't I disable IPv6 with Informix on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, vagrant, centos7, informix

I've been trying to get Informix (Dynamic Server) (`v12.10`) working on a a CentOS 7 VM (provisioned using Vagrant), to accept IPv4 connections (from a JDBC application). The CentOS box version is v2004.01.

I've followed instructions to disable IPv6 binding using
i) creating the empty file (`$INFORMIXDIR/etc/IFX_DISABLE_IPV6`), readably by the `informix` user, and...
ii) setting the environment variable `IFX_DISABLE_IPV6` (to the value `yes`) when starting the Informix server (using `oninit`).

I've restarted the Informix server but this just doesn't seem to work. The only way I can connect using IPv4 is to use a wild-carded host name in the `sqlhosts` file (or explore the `DBSERVERALIASES` route).

Strangely, the `IFX_DISABLE_IPV6` method worked fine on older versions of the CentOS box that I have used (and these older versions did have IPv6 enabled hence I had to find the `IFX_DISABLE_IPV6` method!).

Any ideas on what's going on would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you trying to set up a new system with such an old version of Informix?  Version 12.10 is old.  You should be using 14.10.

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing, for example an error during the start of Informix or a problem in connecting the client, in which case what are the error numbers? If there are error messages in the online.log please provide those. And what is the precise version of Informix being used (as shown by oninit -V)?
As Jonathan mentioned 12.10 is quite old now and there was a problem in earlier versions of 12.10 when using some versions of Red Hat 7, on which I believe CentOS 7 is based.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it's just the configuration that I'm working with. I'm sure it will get bumped to 14.10 at some point. But...12.10 with Centos 7 was working (after I'd disabled IPv6 for Informix) until the CentOS Vagrant box update.

Comment: maybe try setting IFX_DISABLE_IPV6=1

Comment: Or maybe try exporting the variable 
"export IFX_DISABLE_IPV6=1" in the file where you set the $INFORMIXDIR "export INFORMIXDIR=/opt/INFORMIX/"